# PHP - Использование переменной в переменной (строке)

Tags: php, переменные

Задача - создать переменную (строка), в которой будут переменные, которые будут заменяться значением при выводе.

Примерно так:

```
$s1 = "it's $s2 !";
$s2 = 'OK';
echo $s1; //не работает
echo "it's $s2 !"; //должно работать так
```

Может быть я не правильно подхожу к решению задачи. Строка $s1 - кусок HTML кода, который выводится в цикле и переменная $s2 постоянно изменяется.
Собственно я знаю как решить с помощью функции, но вариант с переменным мне казался более изящным.

Comment: Переменная `$s2` должна существовать, когда вы создаете `$s1`, раз она в содержимом используется.

Comment: я понимаю почему ошибка, я не понимаю как исправить )

Comment: Экранировать-то знак `$` можете при создании первой переменной? Или тоже нельзя?

Comment: Это видимо как раз то что нужно, но я пытался - не получается, можете привести пример кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз местами переменные вы не меняете, то используйте функцию [strtr()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php)

```
$s1 = "it's \$s2 !";
$s2 = 'OK';
echo strtr($s1, ['$s2' => $s2]);
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cbc725c89ce1a85ccfc58dd401350b34568ca39d

Comment: Спасибо, думал о подобном. Видимо это самое удачное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте экранирование переменной в строке, с последующим поиском и заменой с помощью одной из подходящих для этих целей функций. Например, *str_replace()* :

```
$s1 = "it's \$s2 !";
$s2 = 'OK';
echo str_replace('$s2', $s2, $s1); // it's OK !
```

Comment: Гениально!)) Переменные создаются в разных местах и конечно порядок создания поменять нельзя, иначе просто смысл пропадёт.

Comment: дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @wakh.ru чтобы своевременно получать ваши сообщения, перед именем пользователя, которому вы адресуете комментарий, прописывайте собаку _@_ .

Comment: @wakh.ru отредактировал свой ответ согласно вашей правке в ПП.

Comment: спасибо, Вас чуть-чуть опередили с подобным решением.

Comment: PS поставил Ваш ник с собачкой, но в сообщении его нет

Comment: @wakh.ru да ) это потому что ваш комментарий не подал своевременный сигнал о необходимости изменений _(я об этом выше говорил)_

Comment: @wakh.ru он там и не обязателен к просмотру, главное что при этом отправляются письма конкретному адресату.

Answer (score 0):

у вас `$s2` еще не инициализирована вот и ошибка

```
$s2 = 'OK';
$s1 = "it's $s2 !";

echo $s1; 
echo "it's $s2 !";
```

Comment: это выше уже написали.